# Taking a backup of a single table in the SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, backup

I know how to take a backup of a database in SQL Server and restore it. But how can I take a backup of a single table, and then restore it? Is it possible?

I have a database with two different names (some different data) and I have to restore one table by taking it from one database to the other. How can I take a single table backup from one database and then restore it to the other one?

Comment: You can't - backup is all or nothing. You can export the table structure using the `Script database object` functionality in SQL Server Management Studio, and you can export the data from a table using e.g. the `bcp` command line utility - but there's no "single-table" backup.

Comment: Are there any foreign keys on the table?  That complicates the restore process if there is.

Comment: @cfradenburg No there is not any

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Can Use Export/Import Functionality in Available in Sql Server. remember to check `drop target table` or somethng like that, checkbox

[SQL Server Import and Export](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx)

OR Create Insert script on Source data and then RUN it on the Target database, after deleting the existing records from the source table as

```
SELECT 'insert into table1 (fielda,fieldb,fieldc) values (''' + fielda + ''',''' + fieldb + ''',''' + fieldc + ''')' AS InsertCmd 
FROM table1
```

Answer (score 7):

Right click the database; *Tasks*, *Generate Scripts* & enable *Script Data* from the options. Select the table and *Finish*.

This will generate a `CREATE TABLE` followed by `INSERT`s for the data.

Comment: In case someone else is looking for this, in SQL Server 2014, the `Script Data` option seems to have been renamed to `Types of data to script` and allows you to choose if the script is generated for just the schema, just the data or both.

Comment: Also, if you set the "Script DROP and CREATE" setting to "Script DROP and CREATE", you'll get a ready made script to restore your table to the time when you created the generation script.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a third-party product such as Red-Gate's [SQL Object Level Recovery](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-olr-native/), that'll allow for you to recover a single object from a native SQL Server backup.

If it's a one-off, you can get a 14 day free trial.